# why have the roast chicken pieces turned brown when put in a pot of boiling vegetables

Tags: chicken

Making soup from leftover roast chicken from the carcass. Has been refrigerated for two days after cooking. Boiled some veggies - potatoes, onions, carrots, leeks, swede, and then put in chicken that was pulled from carcass. The chicken has turned a red-brown colour in the pot. Is it still edible?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the chicken has taken the color of the soup base, as long as it was safe when you put it into the pot it will still be safe now.